# Initialize C struct vs assign members

Tags: c, software-design, readability, code-readability

I want to know what is the best practice for initializing struct members.

For instance, for this struct which option is better and why? In terms of especially readability and performance?

```
typedef struct
{
    int a;
    char b;
} str_t;
```

### Option 1

```
void foo1(int param_a, char param_b)
{
    str_t str = {
        .a = param_a,
        .b = param_b
    };
    ...
}
```

What will be the omitted members, zero or garbage in the stack?

### Option 2

```
void foo2(int param_a, char param_b)
{
    str_t str;
    str.a = param_a;
    str.b = param_b;
    ...
}
```

This option would allow zero initialization (with `= {0};`). But I guess that would force runtime assignment, right?

### Bonus

Also, would it be different for constant values?

```
void foo1()
{
    str_t str = {
        .a = 5,
        .b = 10
    };
    ...
}
```

```
void foo2()
{
    str_t str;
    str.a = 5;
    str.b = 10;
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Option 1 works.  Unmentioned elements will be 'zero initialized' — given a default value which is zero.  It works correctly with `static` variables in functions.  It should be your first choice.

Option 2 also works.  It might be slower.  It is wholly inappropriate for `static` variables; the assignments occur on each call to the function.

Bonus: Using constants instead of variables in the initializers makes very little difference to the analysis — option 1 using designated initializers is the best way of doing it.

Comment: Well, thank you, I didn't think about `static` variables. It is also a good point.